# Join tables and add column only with a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have four tables (a, b, c, d) in PostgreSQL database:

[image]

I can connect these tables with subject.id and project.id unique keys. My query is:

```
SELECT subject_id, firstname, lastname, national_id, project_title, project_id, note_template
FROM project_subject
  JOIN subject ON subject.id = project_subject.subject_id
  JOIN project ON project.id = project_subject.project_id
  JOIN subject_note ON subject_note.subject_id = project_subject.subject_id
WHERE project_id = xxxx
```

My problem is that in table d (subject_notes) one subject can have several notes (varchar) plus selectable note_template (int). I would like to have joined table with columns subject_id, firstname, lastname, national_id, project_title, project_id and note_template. When I join four tables I get result with several same subject rows with different notes. I would like to have table where each subject is listed only one time and to the last column value is added only when note_template=16. Rest of the subjects would have null value for note_template.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last join to a `LEFT` join and add the condition `note_template = 16` in the `ON` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN subject_note ON subject_note.subject_id = project_subject.subject_id
                      AND subject_note.note_template = 16
```